# Azure SQL PaaS and Azure Policy interactions

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Does anyone have any idea as to how I can restrict the IP addresses added to the SQL firewall rule via policy?

I have been attempting it for a while now, my policy looks like the below... i have tried everything - is there something im overlooking? :

```
    {
  "if": {
    "allOf": [
      {
        "field": "type",
        "equals": "Microsoft.SQL/servers/firewallRules"
      },
      {
        "Not": {
          "anyOf": [
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/firewallRules/startIpAddress",
              "in": "[parameters('StartIP')]"
            },
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/firewallRules/endIpAddress",
              "in": "[parameters('EndIP')]"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "Deny"
  }
}
```

But it always throws a policy error when I update the firewall rules despite whats provided in the policy assignment.

For example, if my parameters are both " 0.0.0.0;8.8.8.8 "I would think i could have the access to Azure services enabled and 8.8.8.8 but that's not the case - I just get the same old denied due to policy error.

If I use just 0.0.0.0 as the parameter on the assignment I can provision new SQL servers, with it removed I cannot which leads me to believe that to some extent, the policy is working.

I know I can do the whole vnet route and use NSGS to accomplish just about the same thing; however, my organization does not want to go this route and would rather it be done in policy.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on your question.  However, make sure you are being careful with your assignment parameters when entering them in the Portal.  It takes the strings as-is so if you entered " 0.0.0.0;8.8.8.8 " as you specified the leading and trailing space would mess up the comparisons.

You can check to see what the exact parameter values are in the assignment by using the [Get-AzureRmPolicyAssignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/Get-AzureRmPolicyAssignment?view=azurermps-6.0.0) powershell cmdlet (or similar Azure CLI commands).  To make using the cmdlet easier the full ID of the assignment is exposed on the assignment's compliance view in the Portal.

Comment: Ah, unfortunately, I just added the whitespace in the above for formatting. In the actual parameters, this is missing. I have actually stripped out the parameters altogether and just used hardcoded values in the NotIn block :
`
    
 "Notin": [
            "0.0.0.0",
            "8.8.8.8",
            "8.8.9.9"
          ]
`
With the same old results. Thank you for the reply though.

Comment: It turns out that the Azure Portal is using a technically unsupported way of modifying SQL server firewall rules which causes policies to not get evaluated correctly (it is doing a collection PUT).  You should see that your policy does evaluate correctly when using Powershell, CLI, or normal REST PUTs.  Unfortunately, I can't say when either the Portal implementation will change or policy evaluation will change to fix this.